# kompose creating headles services

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file we have been using to set up our development environment.

The file declares some services, all of them more or less following the same pattern:

```
services:

   service_1:
      image: some_image_1
      enviroment:
        - ENV_VAR_1
        - ENV_VAR_2
     depends_on:
        - another_service_of_the_same_compose_file
```

In the view of migrating to `kubernetes`, when running:

```
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
```

produces, for each service, a pair of deployment/service manifests.

My main question, is, why for all services, the `spec` declaration is like this:

```
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: headless
    port: 55555
    targetPort: 0
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: service_1
```

Why is it creating headless services?

(I would really appreciate a bit on elaboration on what is and what's the necessity of a headless service cause the documentation kind of confused me).

Many thx.

Comment: AFAIK, headless services is used for statefulSet Object. If your pod is from ReplicaSet or Deployment then you can configure it according to your needs. Kompose is just converting docker-compose into k8s resources.

Comment: Kompose is not a perfect solution yet. There will be something to modify when it's necessary to change. StatefulSet Object needs to have headless service otherthan that you can modify with type === Nodeport or LoadBalancer